# Why is this scala syntax wrong

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a map function as such, to take in a list, and apply f to each element and return a new list

```
def map[A,B](f: A=>B, in:List[A]): List[B]
```

only classes can have declared but undefined members is the error given.

PS. I am new to Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because you're declaring it in an object, and you haven't given a function definition. Try this.

```
def map[A,B](f: A=>B, in:List[A]): List[B] = { Nil } // Change the definition later
```

Comment: I prefer ... (Nothing)